# Should I use "referent" or "referrer" or "referee"

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I work on an app, where every user have a unique code, and another person can use that unique code for discounts. Is the person applying the code (of another person) referent? Or is the owner of code referent? For example, my code is haider123, and another person john applies my code. Is John the referent and am I the referrer/referee? Or is it other way around?

Comment: Have you looked at their definitions?

Comment: If I give someone a code, and they use it, then I am a *referrer* (I did the referring). This is a very common usage. You can use *referee* or *referent* for the person who I gave the code to, but these usages are somewhat less common. Often, a longer (and clearer) phrase might be used, like "people I referred." The exact wording would depend on where it is being used.

Comment: @Esther That comment sounds reasonable to me, Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: The referring party and the referred party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I give someone a code, and they use it, then I am a *referrer* (I did the referring). This is a very common usage.

You can use *referee* or *referent* for the person who I gave the code to, but these usages are somewhat less common. Often, a longer (and clearer) phrase might be used, like "people I referred." The exact wording would depend on where it is being used.

Comment: referent is really not used for people.